# Indexing Pandas data frames: integer rows, named columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say `df` is a pandas dataframe.

- `df.loc[]` only accepts names
- `df.iloc[]` only accepts integers (actual placements)
- `df.ix[]` accepts both names and integers:

When referencing rows, `df.ix[row_idx, ]` only wants to be given names. e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['one', 'two', 'three','four', 'five', 'six'],
                   '1' : np.arange(6)})
df = df.ix[2:6]
print(df)

   1      a
2  2  three
3  3   four
4  4   five
5  5    six

df.ix[0, 'a']
```

throws an error, it doesn't give return 'two'.

When referencing columns, iloc is prefers integers, not names. e.g.

```
df.ix[2, 1]
```

returns 'three', not 2. (Although `df.idx[2, '1']` does return `2`).

Oddly, I'd like the exact opposite functionality. Usually my column names are very meaningful, so in my code I reference them directly. But due to a lot of observation cleaning, the row names in my pandas data frames don't usually correspond to `range(len(df))`.

I realize I can use:

```
df.iloc[0].loc['a'] # returns three
```

But it seems ugly! Does anyone know of a better way to do this, so that the code would look like this?

```
df.foo[0, 'a'] # returns three
```

In fact, is it possible to add on my own new method to `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`s, so e.g.
`df.idx(rows, cols)` is in fact `df.iloc[rows].loc[cols]`?

Comment: You could use `df['a'].iloc[0]`.

Comment: See also [GH 9213](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9213#issuecomment-72076683), which suggests `df.loc[df.index[0], 'a']`. This has the [advantage of not using chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail), which means it will work when making assignments, whereas `df[['a','b']].iloc[0] = val` would not.

Comment: doesn't really solve your problem but very good answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation

Comment: Or the other way around, too: df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("a")]

Comment: Pandas should have been made easy to use, people should have not google this question at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A very late answer but it amazed me that pandas still doesn't have such a function after all these years. If it irks you a lot, you can monkey-patch a custom indexer into the DataFrame:

```py
class XLocIndexer:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        row, col = key
        return self.frame.iloc[row][col]

pd.core.indexing.IndexingMixin.xloc = property(lambda frame: XLocIndexer(frame))

# Usage
df.xloc[0, 'a'] # one
```

Comment: Only good as a getter, not suitable for a setter: TypeError: 'XLocIndexer' object does not support item assignment.

Answer (score 84):

It's a late answer, but @unutbu's comment is still valid and a great solution to this problem.

To index a DataFrame with integer rows and named columns (labeled columns):

`df.loc[df.index[#], 'NAME']` where `#` is a valid integer index and `NAME` is the name of the column.

Comment: Seems very slow on long dataframes.

Comment: But it works splendidly. I stumbled on this yesterday and it is the exact syntax I needed to update a copy of a dataframe, linking back to the original by the index and by column name.

Comment: Your method requires values in index are unique. Otherwise it will return a Series with all match index "#"

Answer (score 49):

The existing answers seem short-sighted to me.

### Problematic Solutions

1. `df.loc[df.index[0], 'a']`
   The strategy here is to get the row label of the first row and then use `.loc` as normal. I see two issues.

   1. If `df` has repeated row labels, `df.loc[df.index[0], 'a']` could return multiple rows.
   2. `.loc` is slower than `.iloc` so you're sacrificing speed here.
2. `df.reset_index(drop=True).loc[0, 'a']`
   The strategy here is to reset the index so the row labels become 0, 1, 2, ... thus `.loc[0]` gives the same result as `.iloc[0]`. Still, the problem here is runtime, as `.loc` is slower than `.iloc` and you'll incur a cost for resetting the index.

### Better Solution

I suggest following [@Landmaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754603/indexing-pandas-data-frames-integer-rows-named-columns#comment78451166_28754603):

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("a")]
```

Essentially, this is the same as `df.iloc[0, 0]` except we get the column index dynamically using `df.columns.get_loc("a")`.

To index multiple columns such as `['a', 'b', 'c']`, use:

```
df.iloc[0, [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in ['a', 'b', 'c']]]
```

### Update

This is discussed [here](https://youtu.be/tRrkyYaD9qA?t=214) as part of my [course on Pandas](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/python-pandas-for-your-grandpa/).

Comment: Your preferred solution `df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("a")]` isn't exempt from duplicate labels as column labels can be dublicated too.
So you gain nothing but it's more verbose and slower than `df.loc[df.index[0], 'a']`. For single value access you should use neither of them anyway.

Comment: @Darkonaut duplicated column names are much *much* less likely to occur than duplicated row labels. Also, `df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("a")]` and `df.loc[df.index[0], 'a']` should be nearly identical in their runtime unless df has thousands of columns, but even then the difference should be marginal.

Answer (score 9):

For getting or setting a *single* value in a `DataFrame` by row/column labels, you better use [`DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas-dataframe-at) instead of [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), as it is ...

1. faster
2. you are more explicit about wanting to access only a single value.

How others have already shown, if you start out with an integer position for the row, you still have to find the row-label first with `DataFrame.index` as `DataFrame.at` only accepts labels:

```
df.at[df.index[0], 'a']
# Out: 'three'
```

Benchmark:

```
%timeit df.at[df.index[0], 'a']
# 7.57 µs ± 30.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit df.loc[df.index[0], 'a']
# 10.9 µs ± 53.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("a")]
# 13.3 µs ± 24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

For completeness:

[`DataFrame.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat) for accessing a single value for a row/column pair by integer position.

Comment: How big are the DataFrames? For indexes that aren't just ordered integers, I assume `df.index` would need to do a reverse lookup and that would likely require `O(n)` iteration over the `n` rows. How would it deal with duplicates? Wouldn't `iat` be the fastest of all the solutions and also `O(1)`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Must have been the same `df` OP gave as example. `df.index` is hashed, so `O(1)`. Duplicates won't be ignored, so always ensure you filtered for duplicates before. I don't recall timings for `iat`, but in general positional lookup just isn't always an option.

Answer (score 6):

we can reset the index and then use 0 based indexing like this

`df.reset_index(drop=True).loc[0,'a']`

edit: removed `[]` from col name index `'a'` so it just outputs the value

Comment: That would not return a valid result, because there is no '0' in the index.

Comment: understand the question now, thank you! please see if the edited code seems clean enough...

Comment: @KrishnaBandhakavi , However, it will return more exactly if you remove `[]` from `'a'`. => `df.reset_index().loc[0,'a']`

Comment: This is the only answer that works for making assignments in the case of non-unique indices. Although, in that case you'll want to keep the original index around and put it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just one row, you can turn rows into columns:

```
df.transpose()['a']
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Answer (score -2):

Something like df["a"][0] is working fine for me. You may try it out!

Comment: It will be a better answer if you explain why this work for you and why it will work for author