# How to append to a column in a DataFrame containing time sequences

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

How do I append another list to the column df_final['time_seq'] which is stored in timeseq=[xyz,xyz...,xyz]

Comment: You will need to generate the full new row, maybe full with default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular question:

```
additional_time_seq = [1234567, 1234568]
# i the index of the row you want
# the line below gives you the time_seq list
time_seq_to_append = df_final.loc[df_final.index[i], 'time_seq']
# the line below extends the time_seq list with the additional_time_seq
time_seq_to_append.extend(additional_time_seq)
```

Generally, `df.loc[df.index[i], 'NAME']` [gives you the element for a named column with integer indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754603/indexing-pandas-data-frames-integer-rows-named-columns/45746617#45746617), and since that's a list in your case, you can use the built-in [extends](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method for Python lists.