# Index Pandas Dataframe mixing row number and column name

Tags: python, r, pandas

Coming from R and finding the index rules for pandas dataframes to be not easy to use. I have a dataframe where I want to get the ith row and some columns by their names. I can clearly understand using either `iloc` or `loc` as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df.loc[:,['A', 'B']]
df.iloc[0:,0:2]
```

Conceptually what I want is something like:

```
df.loc[0:,['A', 'B']]
```

Meaning the first row with those columns. Of course that code fails. I can seemingly use:

```
df.loc[0:0,['A', 'B']]
```

But, this seems strange, though it works. How does one properly index using a combination of row number and column names? In R we would do something like:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(32),8,4))
colnames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D") 
df[1, c('A', 'B')]
```

*** UPDATE ***
I was mistaken, the example code above indeed works on this toy dataframe. But, on my real data, I see the following? Both objects are of same type and code is the same, not understanding the error here.

```
type(poly_set)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
poly_set.loc[:,['P1', 'P2', 'P3']]
                      P1            P2           P3
29   -2.0897226679999998  -1.237649556         None
361  -2.0789117340000001   0.144751427  1.572417454
642  -2.0681314259999999  -0.196563749  1.500834574

poly_set.loc[0,['P1', 'P2', 'P3']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1005, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: If you want only first row you just need to remove semicolon in your code like this`df.loc[0, ['A', 'B']]`

Comment: All of your code seems to work fine. I notice with this `df.loc[0:,['A', 'B']]` you say you want to access only the first row ? If so you should leave ':' out of the call, as this code refers to a slice, i.e. from row 0 to the end of rows. There're a few ways to index by both rows and columns, but all of your code works fine.

Comment: Hi, I tried the example df.loc[0:  ,  ['A', 'B'] ]  and it worked (could you provide the version of your pandas so that one can know why it failed in your case) . In fact this example would return all rows because you instructed it to start from index 0 till the end. If you try out it this way df.loc[:0,['A', 'B'] ] or df.loc[ 0 , ['A', 'B'] ] it will return only the first row.   This is just about slicing as in df.loc[start_row:end_row  ,  ['A', 'B'] ]  .
Best regards

Comment: Updated my question above, I was mistaken. The code in the example does work, but in the real case it doesn't?

Comment: Your data doesn't start with 0 index that's why you are getting the error. reset the index it will work.

Comment: .loc works with row labels, while .iloc works with positional index. Your data doesn't have a row with label 0, so, as suggested by @KritiPawar, reset index, or use .iloc (note columns will have to be refered to by their positional indices as well (df.iloc[0,[0,1]]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using slicing which means between two given index. If you only want first row data just use:

Try:

```
df = df.reset_index()    
df.loc[0,['A', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.iloc` (to get the i-th row) and `.loc` (to get columns by name) together:

```
row_number = 0
df.iloc[row_number].loc[['A', 'B']]
```

You can even remove the `.loc`:

```
df.iloc[row_number][['A', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that pandas slicing rules are not as easy to use as they should be. I believe the suggested approach these days is to use `loc[]` with a nested index lookup

```
df.loc[df.index[row_numbers], ['A','B']]
```

I have no idea why pandas still does not have an `xloc[]` or something similar that allows for row numbers and column names. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67260019/1586373) to the same question.

In your answer update, you use `loc[]`, which can only look up row and column **indexes**, but you can see from the previous printout that there is no row with an index of 0. The row that is in **location** 0 has an index of 29. If you use my approach or the others mentioned here, you will have success.